# Creating a fault tolerant parser - properly visiting nodes with errors

Tags: antlr4

I'm gradually creating a fault tolerant parser for my domain specific language and I have a question on how to properly visit parse tree nodes which might contain error nodes.

It turns out in some cases when trying to cope with a parsing error ANTLR creates seemingly valid parse tree nodes which actually contain null children nodes. And once my visitor accesses these nodes null reference exceptions happen because the grammar states they can't be null.

What's the general strategy for such cases? Should the visitor be prepared for this and check every parse tree node for null (even in cases when the grammar says it's impossible) or maybe there's some more general pattern?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Here's a heavily simplified grammar which allows to reproduce the behavior:

```
grammar foobar;

program
  : forExp EOF
  ;

forExp
  : 'for' '(' forIter ')' 
  ;  

forIter
  : varAssign (',' varAssign)*
  ;

varAssign
  : NAME assignExp
  ;

assignExp
  : '=' exp
  ;
  
exp 
  : 'true'
  ;
  

// lexer

NAME
  : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
  ;

//white space
WS
  : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;
```

If this grammar is tested in http://lab.antlr.org against the following code:

```
for(i)
```

...it produces a parse tree where 'assignExp' node is present but its child 'exp' is null ('assingExp' contains an error node though). This doesn't seem right to me.

[image]

I'm using an ANTLR's C# target and a C# generated visitor. The code which leads to a null reference exception is as follows:

```
public override void VisitForExp(foobarParser.ForExpContext ctx) {
  ...
  foreach(var va in ctx.forIter().varAssign()) {
    Visit(va.assignExp());
  }
  ...
}

public override void VisitAssignExp(foobarParser.AssignExpContext ctx) {
  ..
  Visit(ctx.exp()) //<-- ctx.exp() here is null
  ..
}
```

Comment: "some invalid input" is too vague. Please add code + example input so that others can reproduce what you say.

Comment: If `exp` cannot be matched due to invalid input, then it can happen that this `exp` node is not present in the parse tree. But, like I just said, add more information to your question to (possibly) get more specific answers.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original question and added an example grammar with some invalid code.

Answer (score 1):

By default, ANTLR will have a [default error strategy](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.html) causing invalid input to produce a proper parse tree containing error nodes. You can remove this default and/or set your own strategy by calling [`Parser#setErrorHandler(yourStrategy)`](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html#setErrorHandler(org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRErrorStrategy))

> What's the general strategy for such cases?

There is no general case: an error strategy depends on the language being parsed/processed. For example, a common strategy for languages that have some sort of end-of-statement char (`;` for a language like Java), would be to ignore all tokens when encountering invalid input, and then when the `;` is encountered, "reset" the parse and try to continue.

When trying to parse the input `for(i)`:

[image]

then it is not strange (with the default error recovery) that the `expr` rule from `assignExp` is null. After all, looking at the rules:

```
varAssign
  : NAME assignExp
  ;

assignExp
  : '=' exp
  ;
```

it is not odd that `NAME()` will return a node (containing `i`) but `assignExp().exp()` returns `null` because there is nothing there. If you want other behavior, you will need to write your own error recovery handler.

Or if you're worried about nodes being `null`, you could use the [BailErrorStrategy](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BailErrorStrategy.html) instead of the default recovery handler. This will cause any syntax error to throw an exception.

For the record, I tested with ANTLR 4.11.1, and this is what the Java runtime makes of the input `for(i)`:

[image]

I.e.: there is an `assignExp`, but it doesn't have any child nodes, which is (IMO) a reasonable expectation. If `assignExp` itself had been `null`, it would also have been reasonable (again, IMO). But, as suggested in the comment, if you feel the default error recovery does not do its work properly (or some other target behaves differently than the Java target), feel free to raise an issue here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Comment: I use the default error strategy and there's a case when the produced parse tree doesn't seem to be valid. I'll try to explain:

Here's the grammar rule:

assignExp
   : '=' exp
   ; 

exp is not optional and must be present. 

For some invalid input however ANTLR generates a parse tree where 'assignExp' node is present but its child 'exp' is null. This doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Please edit your original question and add enough of the grammar + code that demonstrates what you say.

Comment: Added a simplified grammar, a 'borked' input example and some code

Comment: Well, I don't know where to start with my own error strategy :) With the default error strategy any grammar rule can be null and I really don't want to litter the parser code with null checks... I was thinking of some 'generic' solution where would not visit nodes containing error nodes at all. Something like: VisitIfNoErrorNodes(node); 
But I'm not sure if it's a good practice.

Comment: @pachanga checkout my remark about the BailErrorStrategy

Comment: Thanks, but throwing an exception on every syntax error doesn't seem right for my needs (I'm developing an LSP for the language)...

Comment: Either the default strategy (with null checks), BailErrorStrategy or your own implementation.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what were you expecting for invalid input like `for(i)`? You don't want to stop the parse (through `BailErrorStrategy`) and you don't want `expr()` to be null either (with the default error recovery handler).

Comment: For a default strategy I would expect 'assignExp' node to contain 'exp' child which is an error node but not null. This way the grammar contract "assignExp : '=' exp ;" would not be broken.

Comment: By the way, it seems in some cases the default error strategy follow this logic: it creates terminal error nodes with contents like 'MISSING RULE'.

Comment: Btw, in case you feel there is something not quite right with it, you are free to raise an issue in ANTLR's issue tracker: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Comment: Well, maybe it's just by design... Anyway I'd be glad to create such an error strategy which would create 'fake' error nodes. I just need to understand how to achieve that....

Comment: Note that I added a final edit to my answer. The source is available on Github, so I encourage you to have a look at the default error strategy implementation to make your own. Use SO if you get stuck.

Comment: Yep, I see your edits. Well, maybe I just need to rewrite all the places as follows:

`if(exp.ChildrenCount > 0) Visit(exp)`

Anyway it's much better than checking for nulls.